# Rails/JQuery: Auto complete without loading entire database into browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I know that JQuery has a pretty nice auto complete library, but it does have one shortcoming. You must load all the available entries onto the page from when the page loads. This, of course, might be impractical for larger databases.

I know that auto complete offers an option to only start searching after a certain number of chars. Is there some way, either through rails JavaScript or some combination, to load the auto-complete array after the first four chars are typed in? If there us some other library that does this, that would work too.

Comment: try this https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: awesome. Use this example with minChars option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use any libraries. Just use HTML5 `datalist` and javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/4smuhg4d/3/

When you typed number of chars grater than 4 then will call ajax, and append the result to `input` as `list.innerHTML`

Comment: I don't see how I can access my rails database in your fiddle. I need to run an each loop through model instances in order to fill the auto complete array. Does your solution do this? If so please explain.

Comment: This solution is not specify to any language. 
You have to create API for return option list. And you have to call ajax to your API. After you get data you have to append these data to you input box.